# In R: Why can't I color the dots on this plot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, data-science

In R, I use a self-generated data frame of parties with their seats in an election.

The problem is that the parliament plot is generated correctly, but the points that form the plot are shown in black and I cannot display them with the color that corresponds to the data of the parties. Please help me.

The formula and the dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggparliament)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

colors = c("#783736","#7ca32f","#b59f5c","#7ed61a","#a546bd","#337d34")

parties <- c("PC","FRVS","PH","PEV","COM","CS")
seats <- c(10,2,3,2,6,7)
datos <- data.frame(parties,seats,colors)

    parties  seats  colors
1       PC    10    #38ebe8
2     FRVS     2    #2979cf
3       PH     3    #1f1f9c
4      PEV     2    #7022ab
5      COM     6    #181644
6       CS     7    #e01624
```

I used this formula to generate a parliament plot:

```
congress1 <- parliament_data(election_data = datos,
                             type = "semicircle",
                             parl_rows = 6,
                             party_seats = datos$seats)

cl <- ggplot(congreso1, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = colors)) +
  geom_parliament_seats(size=3.5) + 
  theme_ggparliament() +
  labs(fill = NULL, 
       title = "Parliament Seats") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = datos$colors, 
                    limits = datos$parties) 

cl
```

Answer (score 1):

I think geom_parliament_seats is parametrized for `color` (aka `colour`) not `fill`, and you can use `scale_color_identity` to use those values literally, since they are already specified in the data frame used in `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(congreso1, aes(x = x, y = y, color = colors)) +
  geom_parliament_seats(size=3.5) + 
  theme_ggparliament() +
  labs(fill = NULL, 
       title = "Parliament Seats") +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could also do it this way: change `fill` to `color` aesthetics and the corresponding `scale_fill_manual` to `scale_color_manual`:

```
congress1 <- parliament_data(election_data = datos,
                             type = "semicircle",
                             parl_rows = 6,
                             party_seats = datos$seats)


cl <- ggplot(congress1, aes(x = x, y = y, color = parties)) +
  geom_parliament_seats(size=3.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = colors, 
                     limits = parties) +
  theme_ggparliament() +
  labs(color = NULL, 
       title = "Parliament Seats")

cl
```

[image]